# Remove gs-gwc module

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I am using GeoServer 2.22.2. Is it possible to remove the gwc module? I have tried removing all *gwc*.jar files from the WEB-INF\lib directory and it always gives error.

Comment: Please tell what error.

Comment: why would you want to do that? You can turn GWC off from the GUI

Comment: because I use a standalone geowebcache and want to remove the "Tile Caching" menu as well as disable the geoserver/gwc/home address